# Virtual environment for C library development

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, development-environment

## Original

I am looking for a way to create a non-isolated development environment for a C-library.

I will most likely use `cmake` to build the library and my IDE is a simple text editor.

The problem now is that I do not only create the library but also some sample "applications" using the library.
Therefore I need to install the library's headers and the shared object (I'm using GNU/Linux) somewhere and I do not want to install it to `/usr/local/lib` or (the even worse) `/usr/lib`.

Is there a way to create a virtual environment similar to python's pyvenv (and similar) where I can install the everything to but still have access to the host libraries?

Also I do **not** want to rewrite my `$PATH`/`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, setup a VM, container, or chroot.

The usage would then look like:

```
# switch to environment somehow
loadenv library1

# for library
cd library
make && make install

# for application
cd ../application1
make && ./application1
```

Is this possible?

## Edit 1

So basically my directory structure will look like this:

```
library/
library/src/
library/src/<files>.c
library/include/<files>.h
application/
application/src/
application/src/<files>.c
```

First I need to compile the library and install the binary and header files.
These should be installed in a fake system-location.

Then I can compile the application and run it.

## Edit 2

I thought a bit about it and it seems all I need is a filesystem sandbox.
So basically I want to open up a shell where every write to disk is not committed to the filesystem but rather temporarily saved in e.g. a ramfs/tmpfs just to be dropped when the shell exits.

This way I can exactly test how everything would behave if compiled, deployed and executed on the real machine without any danger to existing files or directories and without accidentally creating files or directories without cleaning them up.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to 'install' the library, you can work in the development tree.

(1) for compilation all you need to do is use -I flag to specify where the libraries header files are, and this can be a relative path, for example in your case you could do -I../../library/include

(2) for linking you need to tell the linker where the library is located at, you can use the -L flag append to the library search order.

(3) for testing the application, you are correct that the application needs to be able to find the library.  You have a couple of options:

(a) make sure the library and the executable are in the same directory

(b) you can temporarily modify your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, in your current shell only, for testing:

```
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=abs_path_to_library:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

note that this will only effect the current shell (command terminal) you are working in.  Any other shells you may have open, or open later will have your normal LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I know you specified that you don't want to modify your PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but being local to the shell that the command is executed it is a nice, easy way to do this.

(c) embed the path to the library in the client executable.  To do this you need to pass an option to the linker.  The command for gcc is:

```
     -Wl,-rpath,$(DEFAULT_LIB_INSTALL_PATH)
```

see [this how-to](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN95)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but this is not exactly what I want, I want to be able to compile, deploy and run the application as if the library was installed on the system root, so I can be really sure everything works, but at the same time not trash my root filesystem.

Comment: @benaryorg, in that case you need a VM or at least a chroot environment.  That requirement wasn't clear from your original question, or more likely my reading comprehension decreases with the amount of time I'm awake :).

Comment: Well, that wouldn't be that much of a problem in my situation, but it just caught my attention because there seems to be just nothing in that direction. [portage](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage) uses a program called `sandbox` which uses `$LD_PRELOAD` to somehow grant or prevent access to specific directories, but sadly it doesn't support temporarily storing the data.

Comment: $LD_PRELOAD, if I recall correctly, causes the specified library to be used first for symbol resolution.  I used it once to defeat some anti-debugging in a piece of code I was reverse engineering

Comment: Exactly. `sandbox` then overrides some functions for file access (I guess `fopen()` and `open()` or similar) so that it can check if it is allowed and if it is, it redirects to the real function, if not, it returns as if there was an error.